# Is it possible that element's name and accessibility id in Appium Inspector have different values?

Tags: ios, appium, element, inspector

I am using Appium Inspector to test iOS app but instead of accessibility ids, because some naming reasons, I must use "name" field to get app elements.

It seams that "name" field in Appium always get value of "accessibility id".
Is there any way to set this "name" field alone in SwiftUI code?
Is it even posible that "accessibility id" and "name" In Appium Inspector have diferent values?